# Huge json object generation through Restful webservice in spring framework

Tags: spring, rest

I am new into designing a RESTFul webservice and I have to design a webservice that is going to respond one get method.

Below are the points that I have keep in mind.

- Webservice will accept start and end date.
- We have to hit the database and have to return the data in form of json/xml. Json object that needs to be returned is having three fields.
- Data is containing large amount of json object and the webservice is going to be called every minute.

I need to understand the best practice to design such RESTFul webservice. Because the major challenge that I feel is webservice is going to be called every minute and we cannot afford of creating new object that finally returned as JSON or XML objects. We cannot cache the results because data is going to change every minute.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you actually mean by data is changing every minute? New records are inserted or existing data can also be updated in the DB? Asking because of caching problems. Approximately what size of json data we are talking about? What about the client? Will you call this rest service by a browser or maybe some other systems?

Comment: Data is not updated by the webservice. There is one application that is inserting and updating the records continuously. With the webservice we have to provide data after querying some table of database. If we talk about the size of data then it is about more than 1 lac. Client can be anything may be browser or curl command. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: It might be a better idea to take a look at async behaviour via  long polling / websocket. Rather than repeatedly requesting data from the service, let the service push changes to the client when they happen. There's quite a bit in Spring to support this, as discussed here: http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates